# ¿Cómo escribir varios datos en un csv sin actualizar el contenido en Python?

Tags: python, csv, table

Quiero tratar de escribir varios datos en un archivo *.csv*, el usuario tiene que introducir algo, lo que escriba se guarda en una variable y lo escribe en el archivo hasta ahí todo va bien.

Pero cuando el usuario escriba de nuevo algo se sustituye por lo de antes, y yo no quiero que pase eso, **sino que se escriba debajo de la anterior** (una lista de contactos mas o menos).

¿Alguien tiene una solución para esto?

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que cada vez que el usuario escriba algo se guarden los datos uno debajo del otro? Gracias cracks

Este es un pequeño tramo del código:

```
with open("productos.csv", 'w') as login:
     login.write((introduce_producto) +",")
     login.write((introduce_precio) +",")  
     login.write((introduce_marca) +",")
     login.close()
```

Comment: Si usas `with open()` no necesitas hacer `close`; el archivo se cierra sólo al salir del bloque.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que cambiar el modo de apertura de la función `open()` de *w* -> *a*. De tal forma que quedaría así:

```
with open("productos.csv", 'a') as login:
     login.write((introduce_producto) +",")
     login.write((introduce_precio) +",")  
     login.write((introduce_marca) +",")
```

El modo *a* viene de *append* que en español significa añadir. Esto lo que hace es añadir justo donde ha acabado tu texto, lo siguiente que quieras, por lo que tu archivo no se sobreescribe.

Puedes ver toda la documentación sobre los distintos modos de apertura en Python [aquí](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open)